# Adding a Value to All Numbers in a Text in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, regex

I would to substitute all numbers in a text, for instance I would to add some value `V` to all numbers. For example, for `V=3`:

```
var inp = "Try to replace thsis [11-16] or this [5] or this [1,2]";
```

the substitution should give me:

```
var output = "Try to replace thsis [14-19] or this [8] or this [4,5]";
```

With RegExp I would like to do some like:

```
var V = 12;
var re = new RegExp(/[0-9]+/g);
var s = inp.replace(re,'$1' + V);
```

but obviously does not work.

Comment: What is `$1`? There is no group in your regex

Comment: yes you are right...I just was thinking that $1 is the first match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `in.replace(re,'$1' + V)`, the `V` value is just added to `$1` string, and the string replacement pattern looks like `$112`. Since your pattern does not contain any capturing group, the replacement pattern is treated as a literal string.

You may use a callback inside the `replace` method where you may manipulate the match value:

```js
var V = 3;
var inp = "Try to replace thsis [11-16] or this [5] or this [1,2]";
var re = /[0-9]+/g;
var outp = inp.replace(re, function($0) { return parseInt($0, 10) + V; });
console.log(outp);
```

Comment: great! I did not we can use callbacks in RegExp!!

Comment: See [*Specifying a function as a parameter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). BTW, `new RegExp(/[0-9]+/g)` = `/[0-9]+/g`.